# They don't know many people in this city. vs They know only some people in this city

Tags: sentence-structure

Why such structure of sentence is so popular in English?
Do you express your polite to "them" in this way?

> They don't know many people in this city.

In fact, "They know only some people in this city." is the same, isn't it?

Comment: It is not exactly the same because 'not many people' implies that they know very few, but knowing 'some people' could mean knowing thousands in a city of millions.

Comment: About "some" I understand.

Comment: You can change my second sentence into "They know only few people in this city." My main question is at the top.